# Pyserial Com3 Port no output? Windows 7

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

Im trying to read data from a simple COM3 USB Serial Port with PySerial.

My Code is as follows:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 230400, timeout=2) #Also tried timeout=None, loads to infinity then
print (ser)

while True:
  line = ser.readline() #also tried read()
  print(line)
  time.sleep(1)
```

Console Outupt:

`print(ser)`
=>`Serial<id=0x2757c50, open=True>(port='COM3', baudrate=230400, bytesize=8, parity='N', stopbits=1, timeout=2, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False, dsrdtr=False)`

I tried to mess around with the boolean-attributes of the Serial object `ser`(e.g. `xonxoff`) with no success

`print(line)`
=> `empty string` or `b''`

I tried to test this in Python 2.7 and Python 3.6.5.

Listing all COM Ports via `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()` returns this:

```
COM3 - USB Serial Port (COM3)
COM46 - com0com - serial port emulator CNCA0 (COM46)
COM47 - com0com - serial port emulator CNCB0 (COM47)
```

When I use the program HDTerm I get the following output:
[Screenshot_HDTerm_COM3_Port_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR0A8.png)

So the Port actually returns something, but I can't read the data from python somehow. The parameters are the same in my Python Code as they are in HDTerm.

Any idea why Python is printing nothing (or loading to infinity if `timeout=None`)?

PS.: COM46 & COM47 are working perfectly fine in Python and HDTerm. But they have other outputs (sending and receiving data from each other only).

Comment: Is it possible the device is waiting for some input before it starts sending data? Try to send it a new line before you read from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself now.

I had to do `ser.dtr=False`

Even though `print(ser)`showed that the parameter `dsrdtr=False` (which I interprete as *"dsr and dtr"*) the attribute`set.dtr` remained to be `True` (test with `print(set.dtr)`.

You have to manually set `dtr` to `False` as shown above. Seems a bit odd to me, maybe a bugg?

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right.
try

```
type(ser)
```

that way you will know the type of 'ser', if it's an iterable(list, tuple,etc...), you can try:

```
for s in ser:
    print s
    time.sleep(1)
```

hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `print(type(ser))` returns `<class 'serial.serialwin32.Serial'>`. The for-loop prints nothing unfortunately.

Comment: you can try dir(ser), this will tells you the variables and functions of the class, one of them should give you what you need

Comment: I don't think that I need to use another function. There seems to be a problem with how I try to read the data, or the data itself is badly formatted for processing, but I don't know for sure.